# Importing stock price from Yahoo Finance in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to import some Singapore stock prices from Yahoo finance in my Google sheets. I am using the code

`=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & A2,"//*[@id='quote-header-info']/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]")`

and put the ticker in A2. It works for some SGX stocks but not the others. Applying to STI constituents, I got something like

| Ticker | Price |
| --- | --- |
| D05.SI | 28.4 |
| O39.SI | 11.61 |
| U11.SI | #N/A |
| Z74.SI | 2.41 |
| J36.SI | #N/A |
| A17U.SI | 3.05 |
| C38U.SI | #N/A |
| Y92.SI | #N/A |
| S68.SI | #N/A |
| C31.SI | 3.75 |
| ... | ... |

I have checked that for U11.SI and J36.SI, the XPATH of the price element is the same as for D05.SI. Below is the link to the Google sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tp9leC43J1W3Jun3Z23K51zmbkZRhPOcM60ffBPOs90/edit?usp=sharing

Could anyone shed some light on what's going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pull in data from Yahoo Finance quite easily using Google Apps Script. In the Apps script, you can define a function to retrieve data from any web page and then parse the HTML output.

```
function yahooF() {
  const ticker = 'AAPL';
  const url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/${ticker}?p=${ticker}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  const contentText = res.getContentText();
  const price = contentText.match(/<fin-streamer(?:.*?)data-test="qsp-price"(?:.*)>(\d+\.\d+)<\/fin-streamer>/);

  console.log(price[1]);
  return price[1];
}
```

In the above snippet, Yahoo Finance's page on Apple's stock is retrieved using `UrlFetchApp`. The price of the ticker is then extracted using regex and one can get Apple's stock price in a Google sheet by using the defined `=yahooF()` function.

I explained this more in-depth in [an article on Medium](https://jasonheecs.medium.com/how-to-import-yahoo-finance-data-into-google-spreadsheets-834e6a7f82c3).